# how to check the history of a page AEM6.0

Tags: aem

Suppose we have a page and it has header and footer links. For which we can edit the value using the header/footer dialogs of the components. Now, I want to check that who all have updated those links in any specific environment. How can I check that?

From the page properties, it just shows who made the last update (cq:lastModifiedBy property), but I need the specific versions/history of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check this in AEM or in your Code?

The sitekick provides a list with versions that have been created. See the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/working-with-page-versions.html).

If you want to load versions in AEM, please have a look at this (older) [Blog post](http://www.wemblog.com/2012/08/how-to-work-with-version-in-cq.html) which describes how to use the VersionManger to work with Versions.

Versions are stored in `/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage` within a node named by the first letters of the UUID assigned to a page (`jcr:uuid`)